# Delete Android Studio configuration folders

Tags: android, android-studio, settings

In the user profile folder I have three Android Studio configuration/ settings folders.

- `.AndroidStudio`
- `.AndroidStudio1.2`
- `.AndroidStudio1.3`

Can I delete the first two folders or at least the `.AndroidStudio1.2` folder?

Comment: I already have deleted one of this folder and I never had any issues because of it. I guess there's one new folder for each version. If you're not sure, make a backup of the folder before deleting it.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - "older" version related folders can be safely deleted.
I have done this and no issues seen. Also, these folders are not created, and last modified / accessed time too is not as per my last usage, indicating it is not being used.

It will definitely help you free up some space (in GBs) :)

Answer (score 0):

To safely delete your old settings you need to know where is your active settings. You can read this tutorial about [Android settings](https://practical-start.blogspot.com.eg/2016/12/changing-android-studio-settings.html) to know exactly where is your current settings are stored